# Middy Unexpected Behavior in middleware execuation order

Tags: node.js, middleware, serverless, serverless-framework, middy

Hey I am trying to write a custom middleware with `middy`. Please take a look at the code below, I am clearly calling `httpErrorHandler` before `customMiddleware`, but still `httpErrorHandler` is able to handle the error thrown from `customMiddleware`, how is this happening, aren't middlewares expected to execute in a specified order.?

I can affirm that `httpErrorHandler` is indeed handling the error, because when I do not call it, the function simply yields a generic 500 internal server error response, irrespective of the fact that I am triggering a 401 Unauthorized error. Why is this occurring, given the expected sequential execution of middleware?

```js
import middy from '@middy/core';
import {createError} from '@middy/util'
import httpErrorHandler from '@middy/http-error-handler';

function customMiddleware() {
    return {
        before: async (request) => {
            throw createError(401, "Not Authorized")
        }
    }
}

async function testAuth(event, context) {
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
        message: "Hello from testAuth function"
    })
  }
}

export const handler = middy(testAuth)
    .use(httpErrorHandler())
    .use(customMiddleware())
```

Comment: Reorder them, where the first error handler that you want to be invoked should be at the bottom see if that works for you. This is recent change in middy v5 not sure if that the version you are on or not